# Updated Telegram from APK - why after the installation, it asks for phone number?

Tags: updates, installation, apk, telegram

I face IMO strange issue with Telegram. The notification says Google Play Services need Phone permission to work, but it has that permission when I go there, however the update of Telegram via Google Play does not work (endless progress animation). So I've downloaded APK from the Telegram site. Asks if I want to update existing, I answer ok, it installs but then asks for phone number. Why?

I updated it, I don't want to confirm the phone number. And the phone keeps showing new messages notifications from Telegram. If I enter the phone number, I have no idea if it installs a new instance or the old one. Now when I click the old icon, it still complains update is needed, but the install went through from apt.

I don't like such app behavior. Any way to update Telegram from APK w/out going through phone number confirmation? Android 9. This question is about Telegram from APK, I do not ask how to fix Google Play. I hypothesize an update is possible w/out Google Play.

Comment: "*when I click the old icon*" did you mean there are 2 Telegram apps now? I don't have experience with Telegram, but the APK from the Telegram site (`org.telegram.messenger.web`) is not the same as the Play Store (`org.telegram.messenger`). By "updating", looks like you installed *a new Telegram app* instead, and that's why the app considers you haven't logged in yet and asks for the phone number. Also, I think the notification for new messages came from the Play Store version one.

Comment: @AndrewT. I opened apps in settings - two Telegram apps. Any place to download GP one? TL;DR:

if apk from the site is for different app, then why say "update" during install? Although truly speaking I've tried it several times and many now it wants to update itself, not GPlay one. I do not see a new icon (maybe it is not on home screen?), I click an icon located on the place on home screen where I used to click it, therefore I called in "old"

Comment: You can try downloading and installing from [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/telegram-fz-llc/telegram/) which is using the APK from Google Play Store.

Comment: @AndrewT., I was able to update old one. And now I have another one. Not sure it adds any value as AFAIK one app can support several accounts unlike WhatApp. Please write a short answer. Thanks! P.S. do you know why telegram has two apps?

Comment: [This article](https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/04/15/the-telegram-app-now-has-a-mysterious-twin-that-you-wont-find-on-the-play-store-apk-download/) explained why there are 2 versions of the app. Basically, due to the restriction imposed by Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram has 2 versions of the app with different package name:

- [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger) (`org.telegram.messenger`)
- [Web version](https://telegram.org/android) (`org.telegram.messenger.web`)

While both have the same name, each app is considered as a different app, and thus (some of) its data, settings, and states are also not shared.

---

What was probably happening in this case:

- The Play Store version was asking for an update but failed to update.
- Downloaded an APK from the Web version and installed it. It's unclear if it's trying to *update the existing app* or not.
- Opened the Web version, was asked for the phone number confirmation but did not continue the process.
- Still receiving new messages from the existing Play Store version.
- Open the old (Play Store version) icon which was still not updated.
- Ended with 2 Telegram apps; one is the non-updated Play Store version, and another is the latest-and-freshly-installed Web version.

---

To manually update the Play Store version, there are alternative markets or mirror sites (e.g. [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/telegram-fz-llc/telegram/)) that provide the APK from Play Store.